# PHP force download, download without naming the file the full path name

Tags: php, download

So our system works by storing user images in in user folders, user folders are stored in master user folders which are stored in one folder called client_folders.

Everytime I try to build our download script (using php force download) the files that get downloaded with the name of the entire file path

Example: client_folder/user_30/client_130/image.jpg

I just want the file to say image.jpg

I have tried several things, explode with array pop, basename() but everytime I try one of these options the variable that the readfile() function reads is empty.

Now in mysql I am storing the entire file path (file name included) in one column, is this the right way to do this? and how to do I download files without the entire path

if it helps this is the code that successfully downloads....just with the full path name :(

```
ob_clean();
if(isset($_POST['file_name'])){
$file = $_POST['file_name'];
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
readfile($file);
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In readfile you have to pass full path, but in header in filename file name for user:

```
ob_clean();
if(isset($_POST['file_name'])){
$file_for_user = $_POST['file_name'];
$full_path_file = "STORAGE_PATH".$file_for_user;
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_for_user.'"');
readfile($full_path_file);
exit();
}
```

Comment: I would remove the header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); as it won't actually help anything in this case.  http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically pulling a file for download using a referenced file path from mysql and you want the download to have the files name and not the path here is what you do

```
ob_clean();
if(isset($_POST['file_name'])){
$file = $_POST['file_name'];
$filename = basename($file);
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
readfile($file);
exit();
}
```

Here is the commented version

```
//This cleans the cache (just a precaution)
ob_clean();

//Grab the file path from the POST global
if(isset($_POST['file_name'])){

//Put the global variable into a regular variable
$file = $_POST['file_name'];

//Use basename() to separate the name of the file from the reference path and put it in a variable
$filename = basename($file);

//I have no idea if this is needed  but everyone uses it 
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");

//Use this header to name your file that is being downloaded, use the variable that is storing the file name you grabbed using basename()
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');

//useread file function to send info to buffer and start download, use the variable that contains the full path
readfile($file);
exit();
}
```